# How does character classes work for regex?

Tags: awk

I am trying to create a regex match, where I want to match towards multiple character classes (hyphen and \w). For some reason there seems to be some limitation in a(g)awk. This works,

```
if (match("this is,not-working",/,\w+/)>0) print "Working"
```

while if I add brackets,

```
if (match("this is,not-working",/,[\w]+/)>0) print "Working"
```

it seems to break. The reason I need this is because I want to be able to do [-\w] to match word and hyphen.

How is this possible to do in (g)awk?

Comment: In POSIX regex, you can't put shorthand classes inside bracket expressions, `[\w]` matches ``\`` and `w`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Do you have an optional way to solve this? Btw, this worked fine for perl, though I know it is not the same.

Comment: Perl uses its own regex engine that is not POSIX.

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew, btw, noticed that this worked fine in this case,`if (match("--",/[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+/)>0) print "Working"`. And also `if (match("--",/[-[:alnum:]_]+/)>0) print "Working"`

Comment: Yes, note that  `[:alnum:]` is usually preferred when you need to work with all Unicode letters and digits.